# (PHP) OOP Design - Generalizing methods

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm working on saving click data for various buttons and links.  I use PHP on the server and AJAX for every button click, sending a signal with some options within the request that specifies which button was clicked. The server receives this, finds the appropriate row in the DB, and then increments the counter value.  If no row is found (new button added) then it will create a new row.

So I have created the following class:

```
class MysqlDatabase extends Database
{
    protected $db_driver;
    protected $db_host;
    protected $db_name;
    protected $user;
    protected $password;

    // Allow for 1 query to be set at any time
    protected $query;

    public function getClicks($category)
    {
        $clicks = $this->db->prepare("SELECT num FROM clicks WHERE category = Five");
        $clicks->execute();
        $num = $clicks->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        print_r($num);
    }

    private function checkCategory($category)
    {
        // This needs to check to see if the category for the button exists...
        $query = "SELECT 1 FROM clicks WHERE category = :category";
        $prepare = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $prepare->bindParam(':category', $category);
        $prepare->execute();
        $truth = $prepare->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(!$truth){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public function addClickRow($category)
    {
        $clicks = 0;
        $query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO clicks (category, num) VALUES (:category, :num)");
        $query->bindParam(":category", $category);
        $query->bindParam(':num' , $clicks, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();
    }

    public function incrementClick($category)
    {
        $checked = $this->checkCategory($category);
        if($checked == 0){
            $this->addClickRow($category);
        }
        $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE clicks SET num = num + 1 WHERE category = :category");
        $query->bindParam(":category", $category);
        $truth = $query->execute();
    }
}
```

---

**CODE TL;DR:**

- $this->getClicks() : supposed to return click data - this is my problem method
- $this->checkCategory() : helper function to check if row exists, if it doesn't, call `$this->addClickRow`
- $this->addClickRow() : adds a new row into the database
- $this->incrementClick() : increments the click value in DB

FYI, class `Database` simply establishes a connection.  Most functionality resides on this class.  Also, ignore some inconsistencies like how I stopped using the `$query` property.

---

I feel like I come to this crossroad at least once per project and it's always the same general idea.  I can have a method return 1 value and takes in 1 parameter and simply loop over it until I have everything.  Or I can make a method with no parameters that simply returns everything and filter on server/client side to only show what the user wanted to see.

---

Short example:  Let's say the user wants click data for 3 links he's created.  The interface they use can allow for options to be specified (so that they can easily select these 3 links and retrieve the data only for them--maybe they have 6 total links but only want info on 3 of them).

As for the code: The method can either take in 1 parameter, retrieve a value, and loop on client OR server side (2 choices here).  Or, the method can take in a variable number of arguments (and then unpack with splat operator).  Or, the method can take in 0 parameters, return EVERYTHING, and then filter on client OR server side (another 2 different choices).  I can practically mix and match these general ideas and have 40 different combinations as to achieve the same result.

---

Should I just do what's most intuitive for the situation?  Or is there some sort of best practice.  I feel like retrieving the single value is the most modular and most flexible but there are also times where it can be inflexible or annoying to implement, say if I want to retrieve all values--I have to generate 30 AJAX requests or simply do 1 AJAX request to a separate method on the server that will call this retrieve method 30 times.

Is there even a word that describes this conundrum?

Edit:  Sorry for the long post, I tried to condense it as much as possible while retaining the key points.

Comment: i would go with both, with 2 different options: either a function that takes an argument for a single result and if parameter is missing, return all (case when the function can "know" all possible values, can be done with default value for the argument), or a function that can take different types of arguments, all results if an array, single if single value (case when function cannot know what all values can be). But i'm not a specialist in coding structure theory

Comment: Hi, no worries.  I just wanted to see some opinions on it and what other people do.  I don't get to see much of this from other people so I like to ask and see what everyone else does and prefers.  Thanks for the insight, I didn't actually even think about having it default to 'all' instead of creating 2 different methods...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what about 1 parameter with array them filter your click using ***in***
>   condition?.

**example** php >= 5.6

```
function getClicks($categories = []){
    $sql = '';
    if(!empty($categories)){
          $cats = implode(',', $categories );
          $sql = "SELECT num FROM clicks WHERE category in ({$cats})";
    }else{
          $sql = "SELECT num FROM clicks"; //Return all row of clicks table
    }
    $clicks = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $clicks->execute();
    $num = $clicks->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    print_r($num);
}
```

Comment: Ohh that's a nice use of implode that I didn't consider.  So this should return all rows with 1 query that match a string of filters 'buttonOne, buttonTwo, buttonThree, ...' else it returns all rows.  All three problems in one, nice!